# Start HLS Recording from a specific position / Get current fragment data from hls.js

Tags: mp4, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I'm using [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js) project to view hls content
I need to implement a 'recording' feature - 
Once a user clicks 'Start Recording' button, all the fragments starting from this position are aggregated into a temporary buffer, once a user clicks 'Stop Recording', these fragments are saved into mp4 file along with the prepended init segment.

So far I was able to listen for BUFFER_APPENDING events and push new segments into a temp array

```
hls.on(Hls.Events.BUFFER_APPENDING,  (event, data) => {
        if (this.state.recording) {
            this.dataStream[data.type].push(data.data);
            console.log("recording " + data.type + " data, " + data.data.length + " bytes  ...")
        }
    });
```

But these are much more newer segments that are being added to the cached buffer and the actual recorded data is shifted about 30s-60s forward from the actual 'Start Record' time

I checked the FRAG_CHANGED event and it seems this is the currently played fragment - [hls.js events](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/docs/API.md#runtime-events)

```
hls.on(Hls.Events.FRAG_CHANGED, (event, data) => {
        console.log("HLS Player Frag Changed")
        console.log("Data = " + inspect(data))
    })
```

How can I actually get the currently played video fragment array to aggregate it and later use it for building mp4 file ?

Answer (score 1):

```
this.dataStream = [];
this.fragments = []
...
hls.on(Hls.Events.FRAG_CHANGED, (event, data) => {
           console.log("HLS Player Frag Changed")
           //console.log("Data = " + inspect(data))
           if (this.state.recording) {
               let recdata = this.fragments[data.frag.sn]
               let dataToRecord = [...recdata.data1,...recdata.data2]
               this.dataStream.push(dataToRecord);
               console.log("recording video data sn(" + data.frag.sn+ ") " + dataToRecord.length + " bytes  ...")
           }
       })
hls.on(Hls.Events.FRAG_PARSING_DATA, (event, data) => {
            console.log("HLS Player Frag Parsing Data")
            //console.log("Data = " + inspect(data))
            this.fragments[data.frag.sn]=data
            console.log("saved sn(" + data.frag.sn + ") - fragment")
        })
```

But possibly there is a memory issue, because I'm  storing all the fragments received in the FRAG_PARSING_DATA event